# Clojure function self reference to get own metadata

Tags: clojure

When I attach some metadata to a function and then call it I am not able to access those metadata within that function

```
(let [I (fn I [x] (println I) (println (meta I)))]
  (let [f (with-meta I {:rr 5})]
    (println I)
    (println f)
    (f I)))
```

I see that the self reference from within the function is not the function instance actually invoked and thus no metadata is available through that self reference. I need the self reference to give me the function instance actually invoked to access those metadata

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired result?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a function that creates a lexical context instead of meta data?

Comment: @Alan Thompson  I expect *(println (meta I))* to print "{:rr 5}" instead of nil and it would be the case if *I* were the true self-reference but it's not as you can see

Comment: @akond No, the metadata of *I* can be "changed" multiple times before invoking *I*, besides they should be available externally to everybody who has an instance of *I* and finally this is essentially metadata with just auxiliary meaning, so the metadata would suit me fine.

Comment: You could use atoms for keeping changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your conflating the value of the function and the identity of the function together. It's a thing many other languages do so it's natural when you're learning Clojure. In your example, `I` has a reference to itself, and looks up the metadata from that reference, which returns `nil`. You then create `f` which is the same as `I`, but with some metadata. So when you run `f` it looks up the metadata on `I` and returns `nil`. Defining `f` doesn't change `I` at all, it just creates a new thing in terms of the old thing. If you want to change something you need to introduce a reference type that you can change. There are several of these, but usually to store functions you'd use a `Var` [(see here for reference)](https://clojure.org/reference/vars)

```
(defn i [] (meta i))
(i)     ;;=> nil
(alter-var-root #'i with-meta {:rr 5})
(i)     ;;=> {:rr 5}
```

Here we define a function in the current namespace called `i` which just returns it's own metadata. We call it to get `nil`. Then we alter the global reference with some new metadata, and call it again.

If you wanted a more lexically scoped example, you could use an `atom` as below:

```
(let [i (atom nil)
      f (fn [] (meta @i))]
  (reset! i f)
  (prn 'before '>> (@i))
  (swap! i with-meta {:rr 5})
  (prn 'after '>> (@i)))
```

However, other than learning how these things fit together, I'm not sure what the goal is. It's probably a bad idea to try and use these structures in a real program that you plan on maintaining.

Answer (score 0):

Rather accidentally, I found a trick that enables functions to read it own metadata. It appears, the Clojure compiler generates metadata support code differently when the original function definition has custom metadata. If it is present, `(meta fn-name)` works inside the body of the function, otherwise it does not. For example, the following produces the result desired by the OP:

```
*clojure-version*
;;=> {:major 1, :minor 10, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}

(let [f1 ^{:foo true} (fn f [] (meta f))
      f2 (with-meta f1 {:bar true})]
  (prn (f1))
  (prn (f2)))
;;=> {:foo true}
;;=> {:bar true}
;;=> nil
```

We can examine the code generated for a function without the metadata in the original definition - there is just the `invoke` method

```
(require '[clojure.pprint :as p])

(let [ff (fn f [] (meta f))]
  (p/pprint (seq (.getDeclaredMethods (class ff)))))
;;=> (#object[java.lang.reflect.Method 0x2b56b137 "public java.lang.Object user$eval2171$f__2172.invoke()"])
;;=> nil
```

And when the metadata is present, additional methods (`meta` and `withMeta`) are generated to deal with the metadata.

```
(let [ff ^:foo (fn f [] (meta f))]
  (p/pprint (seq (.getDeclaredMethods (class ff)))))
;;=> (#object[java.lang.reflect.Method 0x3983bd83 "public clojure.lang.IObj user$eval2175$f__2176.withMeta(clojure.lang.IPersistentMap)"]
;;=> #object[java.lang.reflect.Method 0x547d182d "public clojure.lang.IPersistentMap user$eval2175$f__2176.meta()"]
;;=> #object[java.lang.reflect.Method 0x62c3d0fe "public java.lang.Object user$eval2175$f__2176.invoke()"])
;;=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Clojure, @xstreamer!

I'm going to suggest something different from what (precisely) you're asking for. I don't know how querying the function's metadata from within the function *should* work, really. So I'm going to suggest defining the function first, and redefining the function metadata afterwards. This is fairly simple in Clojure.

```clj
(defn f
  "Boring doc"
  [])

(meta #'f)
;; => {:arglists ([]),
;;     :doc      "Boring doc",
;;     :line     32,
;;     :column   1,
;;     :file     "C:/Users/teodorlu/IdeaProjects/th-scratch/src/th/play/core.clj",
;;     :name     f,
;;     :ns       #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x3b402f0c "th.play.core"]}
```

Now, redefine it!

```clj
(alter-meta! #'f assoc :rr 5)

(meta #'f)
;; => {:arglists ([]),
;;     :doc      "Boring doc",
;;     :line     32,
;;     :column   1,
;;     :file     "C:/Users/teodorlu/IdeaProjects/th-scratch/src/th/play/core.clj",
;;     :name     f,
;;     :ns       #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x3b402f0c "th.play.core"],
;;     :rr       5}
```

Where `assoc` sets a value in a map.

```clj
(assoc {} :rr 5)
;; {:rr 5}

(assoc {:some :stuff} :more :stuff)
;; {:some :stuff, :more :stuff}
```

#### References

If you're confused by the `#'f`, this is how you get the *var representing the binding of f*, instead of just the value it refers to. For more information about vars and how to use them, refer to the [official reference on vars](https://clojure.org/reference/vars) and the [less terse guide from 8th light](https://8thlight.com/blog/aaron-lahey/2016/07/20/relationship-between-clojure-functions-symbols-vars-namespaces.html).